# Don't show the navbar elements on safari browser with boostrap v4.5.3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using boostrap v4.5.3 navbar, but doesn't show navbar element on safari browser. It's only showed the colored line, without the text and hamburger icon. Somebody can help for me?

Navbar Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark deep-orange darken-4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo'index.php?lang='.$_GET['lang'].'&page=home'; ?>"><?php echo $lang['pagename'] ?></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar" aria-controls="mainNavBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item <?php if(($_GET["page"] == 'home') || ($_GET["page"] == '')) { echo "active";} ?>">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php?lang=<?php echo $_GET['lang']; ?>&page=home"><?php echo $lang['homepage'] ?></a>
              </li>
            ....
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your desired `.deep-orange` and `.darken-4` colours as you've not posted css to your question

Worth noting you do not need to use `.row` inside `.navbar > .container` div. Just using `.container` will match the `.navbar` contents width breakpoints to your other `.container` elements. *(until navbar changes to mobile nav, which then the container goes fluid, enabling user to easily reach the hamburger menu with thumb in top right position.)*

Adding `.row` will treat immediate child elements as columns and mess things up in your `.navbar`.

Here is working demo below that works in safari.

Fiddle too... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/dr230sox/

```html
<!-- navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <!-- container so navbar contents are not fluid -->
  <div class="container">

    <!-- brand link -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    <!-- hamburger button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar" aria-controls="mainNavBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- navigation menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<div class="container py-4">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at tincidunt nibh. Donec nec consequat tortor. Sed nibh eros, cursus hendrerit consectetur non, pretium vitae lacus. Nam at libero eu velit tempus molestie. Fusce lobortis commodo
    lectus, eu luctus eros mattis in. Curabitur felis ex, dignissim sed maximus ac, sodales in neque. Nunc eleifend leo nisl, id posuere tortor fermentum ac. Phasellus eros nibh, interdum quis tellus ac, maximus vehicula ipsum. Nam at volutpat massa.</p>

</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is scratch demo of the code above to test on you devices...

https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/scratches/hamburger-bs4.html

Here is what it looks like on mobile safari on an iPhone 5...

[image]

Comment: Hi @joshmoto , 
Thank you for reply but it's don't works also (i added this, and test with my iphone 6s (and also in iphone 12) and don't showed the hamburger icon.)

.deep-orange and .darken-4 is color for the navbar background only.

Comment: See update answer at the end with tests on mobile safari using same code. Can you post some screenshots of what you are seeing on your devices?